# django: loop through images to show one per page

Tags: python, html, django

i want to make the images appear one per page as in "template/1" shows image 1 and so on.

i got pagination from bootstrap but i couldn't figure out how to link the images in my template.

i already have static set up and most of my website ready but i don't have any relevant code to show except this list i tried.

```py
def imageview(request):
    context_dict = {}
    files = os.listdir(os.path.join(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'), "app_name/images/"))
    context_dict['files'] = files

    return render(request, 'images.html', context=context_dict)
```

Comment: you can use code block for code section in you question/answer to make it good and easy to read

Comment: please share you images.html template

Comment: the image.hml template is empty because i didn't know what to put there

Comment: it would be good to save you image names in database table then create model for that table and use that with `django.core.paginator`. you can use `paginator` without setting up with db/model. if you want i can share example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you "Chandan" pagination worked, here's the code:

view.py:

```py
def imageview(request):
    image_list = os.listdir('static/app_name/images/')
    p = Paginator(image_list, 1)
    try:
        page = int(request.GET.get('page', '1'))
    except ValueError:
        page = 1
    try:
        image = p.page(page)
    except (EmptyPage, InvalidPage):
        image = p.page(p.num_pages)
    urllist = ['/static/app_name/images/%s' % url for url in image.object_list]
    context = {"image": image,"urllist": urllist}
    return render(request, 'images.html', context)
```

images.html

```
{% for url in urllist %}

<img src='{{ url }}' />

{% endfor %}


<nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
 <ul class="pagination">
  <li class="page-item">
   {% if image.has_previous %}
      <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ image.previous_page_number }}" aria-label="Previous">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
  {% endif %}
  </a>
</li>
Page {{ image.number }} of {{ image.paginator.num_pages }}
<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
<li class="page-item">
  {% if image.has_next %}
       <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ image.next_page_number }}" aria-label="Next">
       <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
  {% endif %}
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Great I am happy that i was able to help you.

Comment: it would be helpful if you can upvote helpful comment given by anyone if you can thank you

Comment: use code block for code section with 4 spaces for formatting it will improve your `question/answer` and will be helpful for others who are going to see and read you `question/answer`.

Comment: for reference i have added one code block in your answer.